# count divisors problem in python using while

Tags: python

i try to count divisor if number have 4 divisors will print "elegant number" else "not elegant number" but i have trouble while print it i have finished to show divisors from number but my program can't show elegant number or not. i have your opinion to fixed it. here my code:

```
N = int(input("enter number: "))
i = 1
factor = 0 # this for count divisors but doesn't right
while (i <= N):
    if(N%i==0):
        print(i)
    factor+=i # this for count divisors but doesn't right
    i+=1
if(factor==4):
    print("elegant number")
else:
    print("not elegant number")
```

i have put comment in line which line for count divisors.

Comment: `factor` computes the sum of the divisors rather than the number of divisors. I guess you want to write `factor += 1` instead of `factor+=i`.

Comment: Also shouldn't it be ***inside*** the condition? You're just summing all the numbers from 1 to `N`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the main issue inside the code was adding `factor += i` instead of `factor += 1` (to account for a new divisor).
Also, the placement of the `factor += 1` condition had to be inside the `if-statement`.

Here is an updated version of the code:

```
N       = int(input("enter number: "))
factors = 0 

for i in range(1,N+1): # Add N+1 to loop over "i=N" as well
    if N%i == 0:
        print(i)
        factors += 1

if factors == 4 :
    print("elegant number")
else:
    print("not elegant number")
```

Please let me know in the comments section if you need further help. Cheers,

PS. Alternative version using a `while-loop`:

```
N       = int(input("enter number: "))
factors = 0 

i = 1
while i<=N:
    if N%i == 0:
        print(i)
        factors += 1
    i += 1

if factors == 4 :
    print("elegant number")
else:
    print("not elegant number")
```

Comment: what should i do if i want  use while loop not for loop

Comment: @ryand Change to a for loop ;)

Comment: so using a while loop is not possible?

Comment: Yeah, it's possible, please find attached a second version in the original answer. It's just that using a `while-loop` isn't really justified.

Comment: Thanks for the upvote. Please also mark the answer as `accepted solution` :)

Comment: Very well put! The use of a `while` loop is not *justified*. @ryand When you have a very specific range to loop over, it makes more sense to use a `for` loop. You should use a while loop only when ***you don't know when it will terminate***.